# Как исправить неполадку с Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

Добрый день! Сделал обновление Anaconda и теперь не запускается Jupyter. Как и про обычном запуске появляется окно с черным фоном на 5 секунд и в нем две строчки текста, которые прочитать не успеваю, на паузу тоже не поймать. После этого тишина. Запустил Notebook через Jupyter Navigator, но там где обычно Python (default) сейчас Terminals Unavalible. Старые файлы с кодами не аплоудятся. Переустановка не решает проблемы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, кто знает в чем проблема?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: чтобы увидеть ошибку, из консоли `jupyter notebook` команду выполните.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполнил 3 действия, которые помогли в решении проблемы:
1. Переустановил Анаконду
2. Установил модуль portalocker
3. Установил модуль terminado

Comment: Можете принять свой ответ, отметив его галочкой, чтобы пометить вопрос как решённый