# Ошибка UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-25: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

Добрый день,
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему ошибка 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 23-25: ordinal not in range(128) появляется?

```
input_1 = ('C://Users/54292/Desktop/My folder/1_Выгрузка GMO.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(input_1, sep=';')
```

Я открывал уже этот файл именно с таким названием и проблем не было. Сейчас изменил IDE  и проблема появилась. Работаю на Windows7, Python3, pandas 0.19.1.

Для проверки, изменил в пути всю кириллицу на латиницу и добавил явную кодировку. Получилось так:

```
input_1 = 'C:/Users/54292/Desktop/My folder/1_GMO.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(input_1, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```

После этого возникла ошибка:

> FileNotFoundError: File b'C:/Users/54292/Desktop/My folder/1_GMO.csv'
>   does not exist

Comment: у вас похоже все строки - `byte-strings` по умолчанию...

Comment: @MaxU, а как с этим бороться не подскажете?

Comment: А что у вас за IDE? Может посмотреть настройки?

Comment: @MaxU, Anaconda на Microsoft Azure ML на которой ошибка всплывает. До этого была Anaconda, скачанная и установленная с официального сайта, на ней все прекрасного работало, пока я ее не убил обновлением вчера. Теперь она вообще не запускается, я в этой теме писал об этом  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/625085/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-jupyter-notebook.

Comment: А если поставить обычную Anaconda с нуля?

Comment: @MaxU, пробовал, и чуть более старую, которую обновлял и самую последнюю с нуля, но все тоже самое. Похоже при обновлении удалилось что-то критически важное для работы Anaconda на винде. Вчера просмотрел несколько похожих тем, проблема такая не только у меня. Если интересно, вот похожий случай http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043470/what-is-the-ipython-notebook-terminals-menu-option

Comment: рецепты из указанного вами вопроса не помогли?

Comment: @MaxU, переустановил Анаконду и установил несколько модулей, которые в рецептах указаны были. Все заработало! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте явно укзать кодировку:

```
df = pd.read_csv(input_1, sep=';', encoding='utf-8')
```